# Can't update serialport config on linux with libserialport plugin

Tags: flutter, serial-port

Previously [`libserialport`](https://pub.dev/packages/libserialport) plugin worked fine. But now, If I access config `port.config.baudRate = 9600;` it will throw an error `No such file or directory, errno = 2`. Something wrong is happening on the native code side. Similar code written in other languages works fine.

I also filed an issue. But no one around there.
https://github.com/jpnurmi/libserialport.dart/issues/79

Based on previously worked fine. I'd assume something wrong with my computer. But I checked and seems everything is okay. Even the library itself has not been updated for a year.

`dmesg`

```
[  288.638792] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  288.794074] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[  288.794092] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  288.794099] usb 1-1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[  288.794106] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  288.794111] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: A10KUSXQ
[  288.799551] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  288.799647] usb 1-1: Detected FT232R
[  288.801176] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

`groups`

```
hurlee adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev users lpadmin lxd docker
```

`ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0`

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Oct 10 13:38 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Can you tell me what is happening?